# Wrapping a C API in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, memory-management

I'm trying to wrap a C API in Objective-C but am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in objc_release.

Field.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct sc_field
{
    char *title;
};

typedef struct sc_field sc_field_t;

sc_field_t* sc_create_field();
void sc_destroy_field(sc_field_t *field);
const char* sc_get_title(const sc_field_t *field);
void sc_set_title(sc_field_t *field, const char *title);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}

#include <string>

class Field
{
public:
    explicit Field();
    virtual ~Field();

    std::string title() const;
    void setTitle(const std::string &title);

private:
    class Private;
    Private *d;
};
```

Field.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Field.h"

sc_field_t* sc_create_field()
{
    sc_field_t *field = (sc_field_t*)malloc(sizeof(sc_field_t));
    field->title = (char*)calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    return field;
}

void sc_destroy_field(sc_field_t *field)
{
    if (field)
    {
        free(field->title);
        free(field);
    }
}

const char* sc_get_title(const sc_field_t *field)
{
    if (!field)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: fatal error, field is NULL\n", __FUNCTION__);
        return NULL;
    }

    return field->title;
}

void sc_set_title(sc_field_t *field, const char *title)
{
    if (!field)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: fatal error, field is NULL\n", __FUNCTION__);
        return;
    }

    field->title = (char*)realloc(field->title, sizeof(char) * sizeof(title));
    strcpy(field->title, title);
}
```

SCField.h:

```
#import "Field.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SCField : NSObject
{
@private
    sc_field_t *field;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;

- (id)init;
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title;
- (void)dealloc;

@end
```

SCField.m:

```
#import "SCField.h"

@implementation SCField

@synthesize title;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        field = sc_create_field();
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setTitle:aTitle];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    sc_destroy_field(field);
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSString *)title
{
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sc_get_title(field)];
}

- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)aTitle
{
    sc_set_title(field, [aTitle UTF8String]);
}

@end
```

Test:

```
SCField *field = [[SCField alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello world!"];
NSLog(@"%@\n", [field title]);
[field release];
```

The code seems to work fine until I release my SCField instance. If I remove the title and setTitle: implementations as if I were storing an NSString* directly in the SCField the code works fine (I tried assign instead of copy in the @property, too - no luck). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i can't reproduce your crash

Comment: Do you have ARC enabled? ARC will set your title property to `nil` to release the string instance. Since `sc_destroy_field` does not set the field to `NULL`, `field->title` may point anywhere and yield your `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Also, it’s not necessary to `@synthesize` your property when you’re providing implementations for both the getter and the setter.

Comment: The appearance of `objc_release` in your error would suggest that ARC is indeed enabled, but I think the call to `[super dealloc]` would yield an error when compiled with ARC.

Comment: Nah, ARC disabled. Isn't it deprecated too?

Comment: No, garbage collection is deprecated in favour of ARC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that calling [UTF8String](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String) will give you memory that will be autoreleased (according to the documentation).

Rather than using `realloc()` in `sc_set_title()`, just `malloc()` a new buffer and copy it. Also, your `realloc()` parameters are incorrect anyway, so it probably ends up being a no-op. You need to allocate `strlen(title) + 1`; sizeof won't do anything for you since you're just asking the compiler to give you 1 (`sizeof(char)`) * 4 bytes (`sizeof(title)` - a pointer).

Comment: I don’t think the autoreleased string matters since its contents are being `strcpy`ed (which is Apple’s recommendation): it’s a `realloc` of `field->title`, not the autoreleased `title` pointer. The point about `sizeof(title)` being `4` instead of the string’s length, however, is valid.

Comment: But when the object is released, the OP will go to free the `realloc()`'d string, which has already been freed by Apple, since the `realloc()` will almost certainly return the same pointer.

Comment: `realloc` never works on the pointer returned by `UTF8String`, only the pointer on the `field`, which is initialized as `calloc(1, sizeof(char))`.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I typed sizeof() where I meant strlen() + 1, as you pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert, thanks; I indeed mis-read what the OP was doing with `realloc()`. In any case, I'm glad fixing that line solved the problem. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `getCString:maxLength:encoding:`. To get length of string in bytes for a buffer, use `lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:` (takes *O(n)* time) or `maximumLengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:` (takes *O(1)* time).